# grep match a string except matches a different string

Tags: grep

Need to get only files changed in a svn grn (not branch creation).
For this I am trying like this:

Case 1 :

```
echo "   M /branches/Integration_release_23_branch/build/scripts/include/test.h" | \
grep -E "   . /[trunk/,branches].*[^from\ ]"
```

This should match (and it's working)

Case 2 :

```
echo "   A /branches/Integration_release_23_branch (from /branches/Integration_release_22_branch:34500)" |  grep -E "   . /[trunk/,branches].*[^from\ ]"
```

This should not match (need to check for `(from` or `)` at the end)

I am not able to get the exception string working.

Answer (score 1):

Given this input file:

```
$ cat ip.txt 
   M /branches/Integration_release_23_branch/build/scripts/include/test.h
   A /branches/Integration_release_23_branch (from /branches/Integration_release_22_branch:34500)
   dummy line 1
   M /trunk/Integration_release_23_branch/build/scripts/include/test.h
   dummy line 2
   A /trunk/Integration_release_23_branch (from /branches/Integration_release_22_branch:34500)
```

Use `|` to search this or that pattern

```
$ grep -E 'trunk|branches' ip.txt 
   M /branches/Integration_release_23_branch/build/scripts/include/test.h
   A /branches/Integration_release_23_branch (from /branches/Integration_release_22_branch:34500)
   M /trunk/Integration_release_23_branch/build/scripts/include/test.h
   A /trunk/Integration_release_23_branch (from /branches/Integration_release_22_branch:34500)
```

The result can be directed to another `grep` command to exclude `from` using the `-v` option

```
$ grep -E 'trunk|branches' ip.txt | grep -v 'from '
   M /branches/Integration_release_23_branch/build/scripts/include/test.h
   M /trunk/Integration_release_23_branch/build/scripts/include/test.h
```